# Manifold in Milnors Morse Theory

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, soft-question, differential-topology, morse-theory

While reading "Morse Theory" by Milnor, I noticed that certain arguments would not work, if the considered manifolds have nonempty boundary. Example: Proof of 3.5

I could not find the definition inside the book:

What is Milnors definition of a manifold in "Morse Theory" (by Milnor)?
-> more specific: are they allowed to have boundary? do the have to be closed (compact and without boundary)?

Thus: Which manifolds are homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes?

My second question is related to the first one:

In 6.7 of "Morse Theory": Why does $M^a$ have to be compact for all a?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a bit of common sense analysis: if the arguments wouldn't work for nonempty boundary, and it is not specified explicitly that the manifold has empty boundary, then we can probably assume that "manifold" means "second countable locally Euclidean Hausdorff space," which is the most common definition. Further analysis: If there is no explicit mention that $M$ is compact, only that it is a manifold, but $M^a$ is compact for all $a$, then probably manifolds are assumed to be closed. You're sure this isn't specified anywhere?

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but if $M^a$ means $f^{-1}(-\infty, a]$ where $f$ is some Morse function for $M$, you're right that you need some conditions. You can get away with just assuming $M$ is compact but you can do better: just assume that $f$ is proper. Every manifold has a proper Morse function; you do the same argument as the standard one, except you start with a proper embedding $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^N$. Such a thing exists by a version of Whitney's embedding result.

Comment: First: Thanks for your comments.
@MikeMiller: Haven't heard of proper functions before, but looked it up. If the function $x \mapsto ||x-p||^2$ a proper function, your and the arguments in the book should work for manifolds without boundary.

Comment: The boundary story is a bit different. The keyword is "relative Morse function". Essentially you pick a function with $f(\partial M) = 0$ and isolated nondegenerate critical points away from the boundary. Instead of getting a handlebody diagram you get a relative one: a sequence of handles attached to $\partial M \times I$.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment; let me rephrase it. At the moment I am only interested in the CW-Structure. Thus we can assume, the manifold has empty boundary. In this case, I found a construction of a proper Morse function by approximation of a proper function (which apperently always exist) - see Hirsch "differential topology" chapter 6 thm 4.3. Thus, I think Milnors manifolds are closed. Thanks again for your support.